# Symfony manyToOne on flush error

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have problem with creating SingleCase with CaseCollectionsCaseMap.

This is my db structure:

```
CREATE TABLE cases (
    ca_id serial NOT NULL,
    ca_parent_id INTEGER,
    ca_urlcode VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ca_defaultcollection_id INTEGER,
    ca_active SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    ca_author_id INTEGER,
    ca_author_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    ca_modified timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    ca_created timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    CONSTRAINT cases_pk PRIMARY KEY (ca_id),
    CONSTRAINT cases_ca_parent_id FOREIGN KEY (ca_parent_id)
        REFERENCES cases (ca_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE SET NULL
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE TABLE case_collections (
    cc_id serial NOT NULL,
    cc_parent_id INTEGER,
    cc_urlcode VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    cc_active smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    cc_priority INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    cc_author_id INTEGER,
    cc_author_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    cc_modified timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    cc_created timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    CONSTRAINT case_collections_pk PRIMARY KEY (cc_id),
    CONSTRAINT case_collections_cc_parent_id FOREIGN KEY (cc_parent_id)
        REFERENCES case_collections (cc_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE SET NULL
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE TABLE case_collections_cases (
    cc_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ca_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ccca_priority INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT case_collections_cases_pk PRIMARY KEY (cc_id, ca_id),
    CONSTRAINT case_collections_cases_cc_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (cc_id)
        REFERENCES case_collections (cc_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT case_collections_cases_ca_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (ca_id)
        REFERENCES cases (ca_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

This is my Doctrine ORM files:

```
PPK\Domain\Entity\SingleCase\SingleCase:
  type: entity
  repositoryClass: PPK\Infrastructure\Repository\SingleCase\DoctrineSingleCaseRepository
  table: cases

  id:
    caId:
      type: integer
      column: ca_id
      generator:
        strategy: SEQUENCE
      sequence-generator:
        allocationSize: 1
        initialValue: 1
        sequenceName: cases_case_id_seq

  fields:
    caUrlcode:
      type: string
      length: 255
      column: ca_urlcode
    caActive:
      type: smallint
      column: ca_active
    caAuthorId:
      type: integer
      column: ca_author_id
    caAuthorName:
      type: string
      column: ca_author_name
    caModified:
      type: datetime
      column: ca_modified
    caCreated:
      type: datetime
      column: ca_created

  manyToOne:
    defaultCollection:
      targetEntity: PPK\Domain\Entity\SingleCase\CaseCollectionsCaseMap
      joinColumns:
        ca_defaultcollection_id:
          referencedColumnName: cc_id
        ca_id:
          referencedColumnName: ca_id

PPK\Domain\Entity\SingleCase\CaseCollectionsCaseMap:
  type: entity
  repositoryClass: PPK\Infrastructure\Repository\SingleCase\DoctrineCaseCollectionsCaseMapMapRepository
  table: case_collections_cases

  id:
    collection:
      type: integer
      column: cc_id
      associationKey: true
    singleCase:
      type: integer
      column: ca_id
      associationKey: true

  fields:
    cccaPriority:
      type: integer
      column: ccca_priority

  manyToOne:
    singleCase:
      targetEntity: PPK\Domain\Entity\SingleCase\SingleCase
      joinColumns:
          ca_id:
              referencedColumnName: ca_id
      orphanRemoval: false

    collection:
      targetEntity: PPK\Domain\Entity\CaseCollection\CaseCollection
      joinColumns:
          cc_id:
              referencedColumnName: cc_id
      orphanRemoval: false


PPK\Domain\Entity\CaseCollection\CaseCollection:
  type: entity
  repositoryClass: PPK\Infrastructure\Repository\CaseCollection\DoctrineCaseCollectionRepository
  table: case_collections

  id:
    ccId:
      type: integer
      column: cc_id
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }

  fields:
    ccUrlcode:
      type: string
      length: 255
      column: cc_urlcode
    ccActive:
      type: smallint
      column: cc_active
    ccPriority:
      type: integer
      column: cc_priority
    ccAuthorId:
      type: integer
      column: cc_author_id
    ccAuthorName:
      type: string
      column: cc_author_name
    ccModified:
      type: datetime
      column: cc_modified
    ccCreated:
      type: datetime
      column: cc_created
```

In my CommandHandler I have injected SingleCase repo with CaseCollectionsCase repo.

When I create only SingleCase:

```
$singleCase = new SingleCase();
$singleCase->setCaActive($singleCaseDTO->getStatus());
$singleCase->setCaUrlcode($singleCaseDTO->getUrl());
$singleCase->setCaAuthorId($user->getUsrId());
$singleCase->setCaAuthorName($user->getUsrName());
$singleCase->setCaCreated();
$singleCase->setCaModified();
$this->singleCaseRepository->create($singleCase);
```

Doctrine throws error:

```
SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "ca_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL: Failing row contains (null, null, /new-question, null, 0, 1, XX, 2017-12-03 13:22:18, 2017-12-03 13:22:18).
```

Adding CaseCollectionsCaseMap still not helps:

```
$defaultCollection = new CaseCollectionsCaseMap();
$defaultCollection->setCollection($cc);
$defaultCollection->setCccaPriority(0);

$singleCase->setDefaultCollection($defaultCollection);
$this->singleCaseRepository->create($singleCase);
```

Doctrine throws:

```
A new entity was found through the relationship 'PPK\Domain\Entity\SingleCase\SingleCase#defaultCollection' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity
```

And when I add cascade: ["persist", "merge"] to defaultCollection doctrine throws:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO cases (ca_id, ca_urlcode, ca_active, ca_author_id, ca_author_name, ca_modified, ca_created, ca_parent_id, ca_defaultcollection_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, "\/new-question", 0, 1, "XX", "2017-12-03 13:26:26", "2017-12-03 13:26:26", null, null]
```

Calling persist generates $caId, but flushing is nulling it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What db are you using? If it isn't MySQL I suggest u use `"AUTO"` generation strategy for your ids. To see which dbs do not support `"AUTO"` strategy see http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifier-generation-strategies

---

UPDATE: sorry made a mistake. Apparently doctrine still uses `SEQUENCE` strategy if you specify `AUTO` even though it says that `SEQUENCE` is not supported for postgres. I was able to figure this out from this issue https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/6429. Judging from this you should explicitly set id strategy to `IDENTITY`. Sorry for misinforming you earlier.

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6.

Changing generator to AUTO has no effect.

Comment: Sorry made a mistake. You need to use `IDENTITY`. Will update my answer now

Comment: Still no effect.

Comment: Too bad. Can you show me a dump of the last schema update or a migration?

Comment: I don't use schema update & migration. DB structure is already created and I only map sql to Entities. 

Clear SQL with tables is in my 1st post.

Comment: Well that is your problem you need `SERIAL` for your primary key.

Comment: case_collections & cases has SERIAL as ID. case_collections_case has combined PK from 2 fields so schema seems valid.

Comment: It is valid. But it won't generate you your id automatically. Please lookup what `SERIAL` in postgres does